# Progress dialog is showing in wrong fragment and cant pass data when tabs swiped

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Basically i have 3 tabs for the swiping. And what i am trying to do is that show different lists in different fragments(used in the swiping tabs). But i am facing problems or might be i really don't know how to do it.

*Here is what i have done:*

Inside the 3rd fragment's `onCreateView()` method i am calling a `asynctask` and inside that asyntask's `onPreExecute()` method i am calling a progress dialog.

But the progress dialog is showing when i am swiping from the 1st(Top Rated) fragment to the 2nd fragment(Games), whereas it was supposed to show while starting the 3rd fragment.

Below are the codes:

**MainActivity.xml**

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**fragment_top_rated.xml(1st Fragment)::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="#fa6a6a" >

 <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Design Top Rated Screen"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Same codes like above for ***fragment_games(2nd fragment)***

And for ***fragment_movies(3rd fragment)***- i added a `gridview` along with the same codes above for `fragments`.

Inside the first 2 java classes for  fragments i have just extended the Fragment class and inside its `onCreateView()` method - i have inflated the xml fragments.

Same for the 3rd `(MoviesFragment.java)` class, except that- i am calling a `asynctask` to show progress dialog:

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment 
 {
 GridView gridView;
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;

 View rootView;

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
   new GetSearchedBuses().execute(); 
    return rootView;
  }

private class GetSearchedBuses extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
   {    super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.show();
    }

  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
    { }
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    { }
 }
```

And the **Main_activity .java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
            ActionBar.TabListener 
{

        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
        private ActionBar actionBar;
        private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

            for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                        .setTabListener(this));
            }

            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);  }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
                 {  }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) 
                 {  }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
        {   }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
         { viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());  }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
        {   }
    }
```

And the code for **TabAdapter** which extends FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
    public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
   {
        public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
         {  super(fm);  }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) 
         {
            switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new TopRatedFragment();
            case 1:
                return new GamesFragment();
            case 2:
                return new MoviesFragment();
            }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3; }
    }
```

So, where did i go wrong? Or what do i need to do to make it work perfectly- to show the progress dialog in the 3rd Movies_fragment; where i have already done the code(rather than when its swiped from 1st to 2nd fragment)?
I have also tried to call the asyncTask method from fragment's `onResume`-but still the same.

**Another thing is that - how can i pass some data through intent between fragments; when swiping from one to another?**

[Source for the swipe tab code](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

Comment: try putting async your code in onResume();

Comment: i did that too.. But its the same.

Comment: show the code then, I am sure it should work there

Comment: inside 3rd MovieFragment- instead of onCreateView() i have transfared the code to onResume:  @Override
 public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  new GetSearchedBuses().execute(); 
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using progress dialog, try using ProgressBar in your fragment. Define it in your fragment layout, initialize it in onCreateView and make visibility=gone in onPostExecute() method of your asynctask.